# TCP packet sizing at application level for max throughput

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcp

At application level, say using java, how much do I have to worry about the actual TCP packet size? So, for example, I am trying to write an application that should send data over TCP socket's outputstream, do I have to always keep into account the size of the data written to the stream? Since java sockets are streaming sockets, I havent actually considered the size of data units, but the TSO (TCP Segmentation offload) is "turned on" for the OS/NIC, then I can write a 64KB data slice or MSS to the outputstream and thus try to save the precious CPU time of slicing the data to less than 1500 bytes (< MTU). How effective could my programming be, in terms of being able to take care of this dynamically? I know we can get NetworkInterface.getMTU() to determine OS/NIC MTU size, but not sure how it can help that. 
So, I can say that overall, I am a bit confused on how to maximize my throughput of byte writing to the outputstream.

Comment: What kind of bandwidth are you trying to saturate? I'm by no means an expert on this, but I can't imagine that this eats up a lot of precious CPU time.

Comment: not at all, just shove data into the OS as fast as you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how much do I have to worry about the actual TCP packet size?

Almost never.  You can setNoTcpDelay(true); but this rarely makes a difference.

> So, for example, I am trying to write an application that should send data over TCP socket's outputstream, do I have to always keep into account the size of the data written to the stream?

I doubt it.  If you have a 1 Gb connection or slower, you will have trouble writing a program so inefficient it can't use this bandwidth.

> Since java sockets are streaming sockets, I havent actually considered the size of data units, but the TSO (TCP Segmentation offload) is "turned on" for the OS/NIC, then I can write a 64KB data slice or MSS to the outputstream and thus try to save the precious CPU time of slicing the data to less than 1500 bytes (< MTU).

I don't see how give most decent network adapter support TCP offloading.

> How effective could my programming be, in terms of being able to take care of this dynamically?

Java doesn't support it in any case.

> I know we can get NetworkInterface.getMTU() to determine OS/NIC MTU size, but not sure how it can help that.

Me neither.

> So, I can say that overall, I am a bit confused on how to maximize my throughput of byte writing to the outputstream.

The most significant change you can make in Java is to use NIO.  I suggest blocking NIO as this is the simplest change from NIO.  If you use direct ByteBuffers this can save redundant memory copies from Java to native memory.

Do you know you have a problem using the maximum bandwidth of your network?  If you haven't measured this is the cause of your problem, it's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Its more of an optimization at the application level. I am trying to replay audio/video data over secure TCP channels and running into high memory and CPU thread blocking issues once the number of clients are reaching a certain limit. One of the things I wondered was the ability of being able to empty my buffers quickly enough, however, network bandwidth is not an issue since I am using a GB backbone switch on a LAN. Changing to NIO is an option in consideration, however, thanks for endorsing it. tcp_nodelay is not an option for serversocket.

Comment: Using a secure link uses a lot of CPU.  You should use a CPU profiler to see what you are spending the most time and optimise that.  I suspect bandwidth is not an issue for you.

Comment: You can't use tcp_nodelay on the serversocket, but you can on all the sockets it creates.

Comment: TCp_NODELAY is exactly what you *don't* want if you're after maximum throughput. Don't even consider it.

Comment: One of the things I believe I can use is to use Socket.setOOBline(true); for the PSH flag on the receiver's end to kick in along with setTcpNoDelay(false); Will check if that works well.

Comment: @Ashley No, that's for urgent data, which you won't be using, as it is only one byte at a time. It doesn't affect the PSH flag, and the PSH flag doesn't actually do anything. There really isn't anything you can do at the a API level other than what's indicated in my answer.

Comment: @EJP, Oh I see. So urgent data will send only 1 byte at a time. this is a bit of limitation and you are right, wont make sense. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

TCP buffers, paces, decides segment sizes etc behind the scenes for you. There is nothing you can do to help except write as much as possible as fast as possible, and use a large socket send buffer at the sender and a large socket receive buffer at the receiver.